# d3js - line chart `circle` placement to the lines are not properly sets

Tags: d3.js

I am drawing a line chart. in that chart i draw a line by it data values. it works fine. and i am adding the dots on the line, but the dot is not properly positioning. I am missing for some calculation here. any on help me to sort this out?

```js
window.onload = function () {
  
   var m = [80, 80, 80, 80]; // margins
  var w = 1000 - m[1] - m[3]; // width
  var h = 400 - m[0] - m[2]; // height

   var data = [

              {"name" : "city1", value:200},
              {"name" : "city2", value:32},
              {"name" : "city3", value:566},
              {"name" : "city4", value:124},
              {"name" : "city5", value:22},
              {"name" : "city6", value:154}

  ];

  
   var max_value = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value });
  
  var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, data.length - 1]).range([0, w]); 
  var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, max_value]).range([h, 0]);
  
    var svg = d3.select("#graph").append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
        .attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2]);
        
        
        var graph = svg.append("svg:g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");
        
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
                .tickSize(-h).tickSubdivide(true)
                .tickFormat(function(e){
                if(Math.floor(e) != e)
                {
                    return;
                }
        
                return data[e].name;
            });
    
    graph.append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    var yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).tickSize( -w ).tickSubdivide(true).orient("left");
    
    graph.append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxisLeft);
        
    var line = d3.svg.line()
              .x(function (d, i) {return x(i);})
              .y(function (d) { return y(d.value);});
        
    graph.append("path").attr("d", line(data)).style("stroke", "black").style("stroke-width", 2);
    
    
    
    svg.selectAll("circle.line")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("svg:circle")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .style("fill", "green")
      .attr("cx", line.x())
      .attr("cy", line.y())
      .attr("r", 3.5);
    
    //grids
  
  
}
```

```css
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}


path {
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1;
    fill: none;
}
.axis {
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.x.axis line {
    stroke: lightgrey;
}
.x.axis .minor {
    stroke-opacity: .5;
}
.x.axis path {
    display: none;
}
.y.axis line, .y.axis path {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is adding the circles elements as children of the svg element but the rest of the graph elements are children of a g element which is child of svg element. The g element has a translate transform. Need to add circle elements as children of the g element (i.e. change svg.selectAll("circle.line") to graph.selectAll("circle.line")).

```js
var m = [80, 80, 80, 80]; // margins
var w = 1000 - m[1] - m[3]; // width
var h = 400 - m[0] - m[2]; // height

var data = [
    {"name" : "city1", value:200},
    {"name" : "city2", value:32},
    {"name" : "city3", value:566},
    {"name" : "city4", value:124},
    {"name" : "city5", value:22},
    {"name" : "city6", value:154}
];

    
var max_value = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value });
    
var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, data.length - 1]).range([0, w]); 
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, max_value]).range([h, 0]);
    
var svg = d3.select("#graph").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
    .attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2]);
    
var graph = svg.append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");
    
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .tickSize(-h).tickSubdivide(true)
    .tickFormat(function(e){
        if(Math.floor(e) != e) {
            return;
        }
        return data[e].name;
    });

graph.append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

var yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).tickSize( -w ).tickSubdivide(true).orient("left");

graph.append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxisLeft);
    
var line = d3.svg.line()
          .x(function (d, i) {return x(i);})
          .y(function (d) { return y(d.value);});
    
graph.append("path").attr("d", line(data)).style("stroke", "black").style("stroke-width", 2);

graph.selectAll("circle.line")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("svg:circle")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .style("fill", "green")
        .attr("cx", line.x())
        .attr("cy", line.y())
        .attr("r", 3.5);
```

```css
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}


path {
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1;
    fill: none;
}
.axis {
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.x.axis line {
    stroke: lightgrey;
}
.x.axis .minor {
    stroke-opacity: .5;
}
.x.axis path {
    display: none;
}
.y.axis line, .y.axis path {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph"></div>
```

Comment: if possible, can you show me the way how to add the tool-tip and each of circle hover?